# why does formidable 'multiple' select not work with 'multipart/form-data'?

Tags: node.js, forms, formidable

I have tried many ways to parse 'multiple' select options as an array from a from with `enctype='multipart/form-data'` but it only shows the last selected item.

I want to upload files and a select input with `multiple='multiple'`, but it seems like with formidable I can only afford one of them. Formidable retrieves the select input fine with a normal form, but only the last one with multipart form.

Anybody knows a workaround with that problem?

Comment: Please.Give me an example of your code.Maybe it's just rename issue that Overwrite or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "formidable": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const formidable    = require('formidable')

const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
```

Example: [select multiple](https://nodejs-form-formidable-45.antelove19.repl.co/)

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable